Github Workflow using Javascript and Graphql
I am working on building Github Workflows, I want to create one using JS and Graphql. I know that it can be done using REST API, but want to work with Graphql mutations as there are few options that are not covered in REST API.
I have tried searching the internet to find a resource which can help that as well as ChatGPT but no luck. If anyone has built it or come across a resource which explains the complete process would be great. If you can provide the complete example including the JS file and yml file that would great I can build on the rest using that example.
